# TCPDF skipping items after a row and printing some lines of data only

Tags: yii2, tcpdf

I am using TCPDF in yii2, for one single data set, it is skipping rows after 3rd row. This is happening randomly and for just one data set, I tried printing the data set and it looks OK without any missed td/tr/any other closing syntax.

Not sure what is the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found out the issue, one of the row content had < in it and this was causing the whole issue.

So added htmlentities() around each of the content (make sure that this is added for content string only) and this resolved the issue.

So always make sure that while printing data in PDF sanitize < > ? ' " etc. special characters which might create issue in printing.

Hope it is of use to someone facing the same issue.